# Stored procedures that dont work?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I am trying to create some stored procedures in my database for my assignment and I can't work out why they don't work correctly as they run, they just don't have the desired effect.

The first is attempting to add members to my table. It runs fine but nothing is added. It just add's 0's for everything.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `AddMember`(IN `iFirstname` VARCHAR(15) CHARSET utf8, IN `iLastname` VARCHAR(15) CHARSET utf8, IN `iCPR` INT(10) ZEROFILL, IN `iPhone` INT(8) ZEROFILL, IN `iAddress` VARCHAR(50) CHARSET utf8, IN `iPostcode` INT(4) UNSIGNED, IN `iDateJoined` DATE, IN `iNewsletter` BOOLEAN)
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
INSERT INTO members (FirstName,
                     LastName,
                     CPR,
                     PhoneNumber,
                     Address,
                     Postcode,
                     DateJoined,
                    Newsletter) 

VALUES (iFirstname, 
        iLastname, 
        iCPR, 
        iPhone, 
        iAddress, 
        iPostcode, 
        iDateJoined,
        iNewsletter)
```

The second is deleting a member. If I run the DELETE FROM WHERE line by it's self it works fine but when its put into the stored procedure it doesn't work.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `DeleteMember`(IN mID INT)
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM members WHERE MemberID = mID;
END
```

I am a bit confused as to what is wrong with them as I am new to this and finding specific answers is difficult especially as most examples are even more complex.

Comment: There's a common thread between these two problems: it seems like the procedure isn't actually seeing the values that you *believe* you are passing to it.  How are you invoking the procedures?  In what environment?  The gold standard for mysql troubleshooting is the `mysql` command line client.  Test it there, and I suspect it will work.  `mysql> USE your_database_name;` `mysql> CALL DeleteMember(1);`  There is no obvious problem in your procedure code.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Create an id Field in database table with auto incremented values then you will be able to store values via Stored Procedure returned above

Comment: My members table has an auto incremented MemberID field.

Comment: How are you executing the stored procedure? What is your calling code or are you doing it through a GUI?

Comment: I'm using phpMyAdmin and the SQL tab within it.